# Simulating standard input using Python script

Tags: python, console, operating-system

Is there a way to, when a console app asks for user input, make another program (if possible - Python script) simulate that user input? Toy example: Console app starts printing 10000 random numbers one by one and the user has to repeat those numbers as they get printed out to discover the meaning of the universe. Can you make a program interact with a console somehow using os pipes or something similar to do that for you? I would be satisfied if my program could start the console app and do all the work, but it would be even better if I could make it work somehow with an already running app.

Comment: If you're not dead set on having a separate script doing the input, you could always override the built-in `input()` function to simulate the input.

Comment: Have you tried some code?